# Installing Django with pip

Tags: python, django

Trying to install Django from cmd with pip.

```
Python 2.7.3, Windows 7

Env var(...C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;)

    help("pip")
    .
    .
    .
    .
    VERSION
        1.3.1

    pip install Django
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install Django
          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: where are you running this command? pip should be run from cmd instead of python shell.

Comment: Python(command line)...problem solved...thanks..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run `pip install django` from windows command prompt instead of python shell.

Answer (score 9):

under the folder `C:\Python27\Scripts` (or the folder you installed `pip`), press ***SHIFT and right click*** a blank space then select open command window here, 
run

```
pip install Django
```

Comment: Perfect Works great for Windows.

Comment: I had python 3.3 so, go to `C:\Python33\Scripts` using command prompt and run `pip3.3.exe install django`

Answer (score 6):

```
pip install django==1.4
```

or

```
pip install django==1.6
```

or

```
pip install  django
```

Answer (score 3):

`pip` is not run from the `Python shell`. Run this from the `Command prompt`.

```
pip install Django
```

It will install the latest Django 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **user2032220's answer and arulmr's answer**, try to install **Django** within a **Virtual Environment**.It will help you in the long run.

Here's the way to do it :

http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Running `Python34` you should go to `c:Python34`, folder Scripts, and type

```
  pip install django.
```