# How do I install Django on Windows 10?

Tags: python, django

Please help me. All the tutorials on the Internet on how to install Django are confusing and misleading. I understand I can download it with PIP but I have trouble with the environmental variables so I can run PIP through the Command Prompt.

Comment: protip: use miniconda distribution, and save yourself pain

Comment: We'd be able to help a lot more if you could tell us more about how you're set up and what you're doing that isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Django with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491806/installing-django-with-pip)

Answer (score 3):

Just use pip to do it. Open command prompt and write

```
pip install Django
```

And, If you are using pycharm then use

```
pip install django==2.2
```

where 2.2 is the version

If you don't have python installed I'd recommend doing that first.

Comment: How do I create an environment variable that works so I can run pip in Command Prompt

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/ read this.