# How do you install Django & PIP?

Tags: python, django, pip, installation

I am having a nightmare tonight, I want to start learning some Django but I am running into quite a few problems while installing it.

I am following these tutorials - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmljXZIypDc / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEcWRk9w0t0

1. I installed Python 3.7.2 and confirmed the installation by typing 'python --version' into Terminal/Command Prompt.
2. I typed 'pip --version' into CMD and got this message in return "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

this is where I am stuck, I cannot continue any longer without completing this step, could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you

edit: looks like it's a path issue, does anyone know how to do the following: how to I do this :

"Then add C:\Python37\Scripts path to your environment variable. Assumes that there is a Python37 folder in your C drive, that folder name may varied according to the installed python version Now you can install python packages by running pip install awesome_package_name"

Comment: Try `python -m ensurepip` first.

Comment: how to I do this : "Then add C:\Python37\Scripts path to your environment variable. Assumes that there is a Python37 folder in your C drive, that folder name may varied according to the installed python version

Now you can install python packages by running

pip install awesome_package_name"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uninstall python and when you're installing python again , check on add python to PATH.It will remove the error

Comment: Thanks, will try this now.

Comment: This seemed to work, now everything works. Thank you Gagan Singh

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific as to which OS you are using? You can use pip also like `python -m pip ...`. The `-m` part loads a python module It might just not be installed since it is a python module. On linux, for example you have to install pip separately (would be `sudo apt-get install python-pip`).

Comment: I am on windows 10 my friend

Comment: do you use powershell? if it is installed, try running ```pip install django``` from it, as suggested by sam.

Comment: if you see ">>>" before what you are typing, you are in the python shell and pip install ... or something like that won't work :-)

Comment: I have tried entering pip install django into powershell, here's what I get: pip: the term pip is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: have you tried using ```python -m pip install  django``` from powershell?

Comment: also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963446/how-to-install-packages-with-pip-in-windows-powershell for a possible PATH related issue.

Comment: thanks, I think it maybe a path issue. I typed in 'python -m pip install django' and this is what I get: https://prnt.sc/q253gb

Comment: you can just add the directory to the PATH, so you don't have import issues later on :-)

Answer (score 0):

Run pip install django from windows command prompt instead of python shell.

[Installing Django with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491806/installing-django-with-pip#15491926)

follow these to know more. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/install/
hope you will get it.

Comment: how to I do this : "Then add C:\Python37\Scripts path to your environment variable. Assumes that there is a Python37 folder in your C drive, that folder name may varied according to the installed python version Now you can install python packages by running pip install awesome_package_name"